Why is ExitProcess 0 throwing access violation exception?
I'm trying to put together a simple code for a class, but the only problem I'm having is the exit process. It keeps throwing the error "Exception thrown at 0x009F1058 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000003." I have no idea what is happening. Help.
Here's the code:
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data

.code
main proc
     ; 16-bit registers
    mov ax, 1       ; Test AX
    mov bx, 2       ; Test BX
    mov cx, 3       ; Test CX
    mov dx, 4       ; Test DX
    mov si, 5       ; Test SI
    mov di, 6       ; Test DI
    mov sp, 7       ; Test SP
    mov bp, 8       ; Test BP
    ; mov ip, 9  ; Instruction Pointer (not modifiable in user mode)

    ; 32-bit registers
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, 3
    mov edx, 4
    mov esi, 5
    mov edi, 6
    mov esp, 7  ; Stack Pointer
    mov ebp, 8  ; Base Pointer
    ; eip is not modifiable in user mode
    ; efl (Flags Register) cannot be modified 

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main

I don't know what I'm doing, since I'm very new to assembly. I can't find any information on this specific problem with vs, but I've been bashing my head against this for a week. Nothing changes.

Certain registers must contain sensible values at all times when control goes from one function to another - esp is of particular importance here. Also, note that ax is a subset of eax's bits, bx is a subset of ebx, and so on.

It's kind of unreasonable to not know what you are doing, and yet expect a particular result. What do you want to achieve with this code? You're putting a bunch of random values into a bunch of registers. Why?

@NateEldredge The assignment was just to show that you can move registers. I got the code to do that. The problem is that the program won't exit.

Because registers have meaning, and overwriting them has consequences. Since the whole program uses the stack, overwriting the stack pointer will wreck everything, including your ability to call functions such as ExitProcess. What you've done is analogous to taking a bike, smashing it with a hammer, and then complaining that it won't go.

@NateEldredge oh my god thank you. Now it runs, since I commented out the sp, bp, esp, and ebp moves. Thank you so much for clarifying this.

eip is not modifiable in user mode - incorrect, jmp foo sets EIP=foo.  It's not a general-purpose register so it can't be an operand for mov regardless of user vs. supervisor mode, but you can write it with jumps and read it with call (and in 64-bit mode only, with LEA with a RIP-relative addressing mode.)  Related: Why isn't the instruction pointer a normal register usable with MOV or ADD? and Reading program counter directly

Knowing what the problem is, I found a duplicate by searching on site:stackoverflow.com call "mov ESP" crash.
